# Printing all destination IP addresses using C++

Tags: c++, windows, ip, sniffing

Is there any way to print all of the IP addresses that I'm sending packets to using C++ on Windows? I've tried to sniff my traffic with WinSock2 but I had to run my code with administrator permissions. Is there any way to do it with user permissions too?

Comment: To capture traffic without admin rights, you would have to use a capture library like [WinPCap](https://www.winpcap.org/) or [Npcap](https://nmap.org/npcap/) (which are what Wireshark uses on Windows), [libpcap](https://www.tcpdump.org), etc

Comment: Imagine how huge a security hole that would be.

Comment: @RemyLebeau really? they allow that?

Comment: @numzero Yes. They use a kernel-level driver to bypass the admin restriction, feeding data from the network up into user space where non-admin processes can access it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau um, but that needs a kernel driver whose installation *does* require admin rights (I assume it’s not built-in). Still wondering of their “security” model.

Comment: @numzero Sure, *installation* needs to be done by an admin (like most things), but then a non-admin can *use* it afterwards

Comment: @RemyLebeau Made it with WinPcap and it works great, thanks!:)